# What kind of switch (SP4T) is ok for short periods (100-200us) of 85V, 16A?

Tags: current, switches

I am looking for a switch that is a SP3T switch that can handle 85VDC and 16A.  The 85V, 16A reqiurement is only for short periods of time (100-200us). The switch I need to use will connect a PU, PD, and load (injector).

I am looking for something somewhat cheap because I found some that are close 125VDC and 15A, but these are like $80 a switch and I need 15 of them. I am not really sure if it is necessary due to the short on-times (specified above).

Comment: The thermal timeconstant of 1mm cube of silicon (assume this is ~same for metals in the switch contacts) is 11.4 milliSeconds. Thus thermal burden is OK. Are these switches only switched when the loads are OFF? otherwise inductance-stored-energy may require quenching of arcs.

Comment: Yeah, there would be a HS and LS switch with the load in the middle.  The load cannot be ON until the switch turned on from the HS... it is possible for the LS switch to be switched when the load is on, but this is controlled by software, so we could always turn off the load before changing the switch.